# Nativescript scroll doesn't work with stackLayout

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to learn nativescript and found 2 seperate projects and trying to combine them but when I do that scroll doesn't work can you explain why or what I'm doing wrong.

**Here is my code**

```
<ActionBar title="myApp" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>


  <GridLayout class="page" orientation="vertical">

    <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" [text]="item.name" 
      class="list-group-item"></Label>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>

</GridLayout>
<TabView #tabview [selectedIndex]="tabindex" class="tab-view" 
 selectedColor="#4099FF" >

 <StackLayout align="top" *tabItem="{title:'Home',iconSource:'res://home'}">
    <home-tab></home-tab>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Explore', iconSource:'res://explore'}">
    <Label class="border" borderWidth="5" borderColor="black" text="hey">
</Label>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Notifications', 
iconSource:'res://notifications'}">
   </StackLayout>


</TabView>
```

Here at top I have tabs and under that I have list of items but can't scroll down it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Use `<ScrollView> </ScrollView>` around the content you want to scroll. https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/scroll-view